# Undo suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

If I suggest an edit for another's post and immediately realize that I've missed something, I can re-edit it. But can I undo suggested edits (bring the post to the original or previous state) before it is approved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. You have to wait for the edit to be either approved or rejected. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933), [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307514) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317347).

Comment: *"See this post, this post and this post."* All three posts are the same.

Comment: @ACB The original post is from 2011 (over a decade ago), so I thought I'd link some more recent posts as well.

Comment: @ACB The second and third linked posts have been closed as duplicates of the first question. Since you don't currently have an account on Meta Stack Exchange, you will be automatically redirected to the original question (#1) on clicking these links. If you would like to see these posts without being redirected, please add `?noredirect=1` to the end of the URL, or create an account on Meta Stack Exchange.